# What is the maximum bike distance for the HERE Intermodal Routing API V8

Tags: routes, here-api

For walking there is the `pedestrian[maxDistance]` parameter. But there is nothing similar for biking.

When trying to use bike and ride I can get the error:

```
{
        "title": "Routing is not possible due to missing stations in a given range",
        "code": "noStationsFound"
}
```

However I can't find any documentation on what the "given range" is. Does anyone know what the maximum length for a cycling leg is in the intermodal API? Also does anyone know what range the intermodal uses for finding stations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer from customer support - only took six weeks.

The answer is 5km - as measured by road network not straight line distance.

This limit cannot be altered.

Additionally, the limit for driving to a station for drive and ride results is 50km.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API exist for bike maxDistance similar to pedestrian[maxDistance].

With Bike & ride option ("vehicle[modes]=bicycle") will be returned only if it significantly improves the transit route for the same request. If that is not the case, only transit route will be returned

To help us further check the error message please share the API request?

The range for pedestrian[maxDistance] available here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/public-transit/migration_guide/topics/transit-routing-migration.html

[image]